# Mech suit anime where the pilot gets full control over the suit if the mech decides to merge with them

Tags: story-identification, anime

Looking for a mech anime series where if the mech suit chooses to merge with the human pilot, he receives total control over the suit but if destroyed in combat will die with the suit. The main character is a young male who takes over the suit after the original owner dies. When the mech decides to merge with the pilot it happens with a bunch of black cables that insert into his skin.

I remember it was dubbed in English but the main title was in a different language. Maybe the title has it in English in small print but it’s been so long.

I watched it on YouTube. The main character didn’t know the original owner but was told the story about who the suit belonged to, and how total control was possible. The suit chose to bond with the pilot usually when the fight was almost one sided. I don’t believe the suit had a voice or even displayed emotion, it was either the suit liked you or didn’t so you didn’t bind with it. Once you had total control, everything you did was heightened, reflexes, actions all of it.